# Running Ubuntu natively on MacBook Pro, with OSX inside VMWare?

Tags: linux, virtualization, mac, vmware-workstation

So I have a mid-2012 MacBook Pro (non-Retina) currently running OSX 10.11. However, I'm not the biggest fan of recent versions of OSX. The machine still suits my needs perfectly hardware wise, and I'm not really in a position to purchase a new machine.

I'm thinking of installing Ubuntu 16.04LTS natively on my MBP. For my day to day use, this'll be great. However, my issue is that every now and again I need to use XCode and iTunes (it really is an occasional thing).

For this, I was thinking I could run OSX inside VMWare on top of the native Ubuntu. Is this possible and legit?

Thanks.

Comment: VMware allows you to create a virtual machine from an existing installation on a physical drive. I have tested this in Ubuntu for a Windows installation, and I assume it will work for OSX, though I have no idea how licensing will work.

Comment: A quick skim through [this guide](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~somlo/OSXKVM/) suggests it's technically possible using QEMU and KVM on Fedora. **IANAL**, but legally (as far as a EULA is enforceable) it might not be allowed. Sections 2A and 2B(i) of the [El Capitan EULA](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX1011.pdf) (PDF link) seems to say you're allowed one copy running directly on Apple hardware, i.e. no virtualization. Section 2B(iii) says you can run 2 more copies of the Apple software in a virtual OS environment on a Mac that is *already running the Apple software*.

Comment: @NOP - Considering you can run a OS X VM from within Windows, running on a Macbook, it all depends compatability with VMWare on Linux  Simplest way to find out is to try.